# USB-C to DisplayPort not recognized on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb-c

My laptop is an Asus ZenBook UX431FA-AM076T. [Site describes](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-14-UX431FA/Tech-Specs/) it has a USB 3.1, gen2 port.

I've attached a USB-C to an external monitor with DisplayPort, however, it's not recognized.

- The external monitor is recognized with same cable on other laptop with a Thunderbolt port
- Running kernel version is `5.0.0-31-generic` on `Ubuntu 18.04`
- Kernel module `typec_displayport` is loaded
- No special BIOS settings are present regarding monitor/USB or other stuff, UEFI is turned off
- Seems that the maximum size is 5000M, which is weird in my opinion;

  ```
  >  ~  sudo lsusb -t
  /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
  ```

  - I've installed latest `DisplayLink`, no success either.

Kernel is compiled with TYPEC_DP_ALTMODE

```
>  ~ cat /boot/config-5.0.0-31-generic | grep TYPEC_DP
CONFIG_TYPEC_DP_ALTMODE=m
```

I'm not sure where the problem lies. It's almost 2020, this should be fixed in the kernel, right?
Can someone point me in the right direction to fix this matter.

Comment: Where does the device specifications state that the hardware itself does in fact support DisplayPort alt mode on the USB-C connector? Does the laptop support Thunderbolt 3? Is the cable for alt mode (aka SlimPort), or for Thunderbolt 3 (they are not the same interface)? Does the same cable work under Windows on the same laptop?

Comment: 1. That's general knowledge, usb 3.1 Gen2 support DP alt mode..
2. No, as shown in the specs it does not. 
3. Cable description is; USB 3.1 Type-C to DisplayPort

Haven't tested on Windows, but not going to install Windows, because Windows

Comment: No, all devices with USB 3.1 Gen 2 do not support DP alt mode. USB-C devices may/can support DP alt mode, MHL alt mode, or ThunderBolt 3, if so implemented, but these are all different, and none are guaranteed to be supported just because a device has a 3.1 Gen 2 type C USB connector. The hardware must be specifically wired to support them, and the firmware must support it. DisplayLink is something completely different. It seems like you're making an assumption of what is supported by the hardware, simply based on the connector types. It sounds like cable may be TB3 though.

Comment: how can I verify if my hardware supports it?

Comment: Was `typec_displayport` loaded automatically, or did you manually load it?  Does the laptop where the cable does work, have that module loaded? Do you have a phone which supports USB-C SlimPort such as HTC 10, Samsung Galaxy S7 or newer, etc…? Even if our laptop supports DP alt mode, if the cable does not because it is a TB3 cable instead, it won't work and you need a different cable that is for Slimport/DP alt mode. If it doesn't work on a Slimport USB-C supporting phone, then it's not a DP alt mode cable. Also, check `lshw` on the laptop where it works, to see what is used there?

Comment: Special drivers may be required for USB 3.1 Gen 2 functionality. Asus only provides such drivers for Windows https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-14-UX431FA/HelpDesk_Download/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems there is a list of Asus to state whether a laptop supports Video output or not: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1031591/

When looking at the logo's of the port, it seems my laptop does not support video output.

Wish there was a command to verify this.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on a Dell G7. In my case, it is the USB-C cable that was the issue. Make sure to try with the cable provided by the screen manufacturer.

Comment: Apparently the chip inside of a cable matters, I have several chipped usb-c cables and only two of them work. try with the cable supplied by the screen manufacturer, in my case ugreen cable failed, asus ones work fine